# Can´t convert JSON to JSONObject

Tags: php, android, json

Here´s the JSON that my php file delivers:

```
[{"id":"408","punktezahl":"15","name":"testname","email":"hsksjs","datum":"24.01.14 17:11","wohnort":"Vdhdhs","newsletter":"J"}]
```

When I try to access the JSON Object like this

```
public void connect(){
    System.out.println("%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%1" );
    Thread t = new Thread(){
        @Override
        public void run() {
    try {
        System.out.println("%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%2" );
        HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
        HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(params, 0);
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(params);
        String urlString = "http://url";
        //prepare the HTTP GET call 
        HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(urlString);
        //get the response entity
        HttpEntity entity = httpClient.execute(httpget).getEntity();
        System.out.println("%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%3" );
        if (entity != null) {
            //get the response content as a string
            String response = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
            //consume the entity
            entity.consumeContent();

            // When HttpClient instance is no longer needed, shut down the connection manager to ensure immediate deallocation of all system resources
            httpClient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();

            //return the JSON response

            JSONObject parentObject = new JSONObject(response);
            JSONObject userDetails = parentObject.getJSONObject("output"); 


             String name = userDetails.getString("name");
             System.out.println("HEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE" + name);
               }



    }catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

};
t.start();
}
```

I get the following error:

```
01-24 18:18:21.746: W/System.err(20673): org.json.JSONException: Value [{"id":"408","datum":"24.01.14 17:11","punktezahl":"15","email":"hsksjs","newsletter":"J","wohnort":"Vdhdhs","name":"testname"}] of type org.json.JSONArray cannot be converted to JSONObject
01-24 18:18:21.746: W/System.err(20673):    at org.json.JSON.typeMismatch(JSON.java:111)
01-24 18:18:21.746: W/System.err(20673):    at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:159)
01-24 18:18:21.746: W/System.err(20673):    at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:172)
01-24 18:18:21.746: W/System.err(20673):    at com.wuestenfest.jagdenwilli.Highscore_zeigen$1.run(Highscore_zeigen.java:82)
```

Where´s my mistake?

Comment: This because you have json array as a base object in which you have json object..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your response is a `JSONArray` not a `JSOnObject`.

So change

```
  JSONObject parentObject = new JSONObject(response);
```

to

```
 JSONArray jsonarray = new JSONArray(response);
```

Your JSON

```
[ // json array node
    { // jsson onject npode
        "id": "408",
        "punktezahl": "15",
        "name": "testname",
        "email": "hsksjs",
        "datum": "24.01.14 17:11",
        "wohnort": "Vdhdhs",
        "newsletter": "J"
    }
]
```

I do not see any json object `output` either in the above json. So

```
    JSONObject userDetails = parentObject.getJSONObject("output");
```

is also wrong.

Parsing

```
  JSONArray jsonarray = new JSONArray(response); 
  JSONObject jb =(JSONObject) jsonarray.getJSONObject(0);
  String name= jb.getString("name");
```

Comment: Great, now I understand the difference between the JSONArray and JSONObject, thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is just as the exception describes: you are trying to parse your response object into a JSONObject, but it is actually a JSONArray (as seen by the square brackets).  In stead, parse it as a JSONArray, and get the first element from the array, which would be your desired JSONObject.